# CentOS with Python as base image

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile

I created a Dockerfile and then built it for my team to use. Currently I am pulling from the CentOS:latest image, then building the latest version of Python and saving the image to a .tar file. The idea is for my colleagues to use this image to add their Python projects to the /pyscripts folder. Is this the recommended way of building a base image or is there a better way I can go about doing it?

```
# Filename: Dockerfile
From centos

RUN yum -y update && yum -y install gcc openssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel wget make && yum clean all

RUN cd /opt && wget --no-check-certificate https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.3/Python-3.8.3.tgz && tar xzf Python-3.8.3.tgz && cd Python-3.8*/ && ./configure --enable-optimizations && make altinstall && rm -rf /opt/Python* && mkdir /pyscripts
```

Many thanks!

Comment: The Dockerfile seems fine (I wouldn't `mkdir` an empty directory but let derived images do it on their own).  I'd generally have your CI system push the image to a Docker registry; `docker save` is a little clunky and I'd avoid it if possible.  Is there a specific problem you're running into with this?

Comment: @DavidMaze, thanks for the suggestions. I actually did not know that I could have my own private docker registry. I actually looked at some Youtube tutorials and it seems pretty easy to get it running. I am not running into any issues, just wanted to know if what I did was the recommended way of making a base image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is the standard and recommended way of building a base image from a parent image (CentOS in this example) if that is what you need Python `3.8.3` (`latest` version) on CentOS system.

Alternatively you can pull a generic Python image with latest Python version (which is now `3.8.3`) but based on other Linux distribution (Debian) from Docker HUB repository by running:

```
docker pull python:latest
```

And then build a base image from it where you will just need to create the directory /pyscripts
So the Dockerfile would look like that:

```
FROM python:latest
RUN mkdir /pyscripts
```

Or you can pull CentOS/Python already built image (with lower version `3.6`) from Docker HUB repository by running:

```
docker pull centos/python-36-centos7
```

And then build a base image from it where you will just need to create the directory `/pyscripts`
So the Dockerfile would look like that:

```
FROM centos/python-36-centos7:latest
USER root
RUN mkdir /pyscripts
```

Remember to add this line just after the first line to run the commands as root:

```
USER root
```

Otherwise you would get a `Permission Denied` error message

Comment: No clue what you wrote that answer in as it contained `<br>` and other strange formatting, but please check the [formatting section](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for writing better answers. :)

Comment: The format now is better , I was doing that in the HTML format , and <br> is an HTML tag for braking line i.e. taking new line , I though It should be OK to put HTML tags in the HTML format section,  as this is supposed to be what it is there for. 

I did that because at some part the normal Carriage Return did not give me new line. 

I Will check the formatting section provided.

Comment: @emadelbieh, my understanding was the docker images are usually root already. Maybe could you explain more about the USER root? Thanks for your detailed answer.

Comment: Yes by default docker run commands as root but If an image was generated from a source that changed root to a user in the build time then all commands issued in the RUN section will run as the other user, and actually this is the case with the image "centos/python-36-centos7:latest" for some reason it was built with user "Default" instead of "root" , and also it doesn't have "sudo" installed on it, that is why I mentioned USER root only for that specific image because I tried it before.

Comment: @emadelbieh Now I get what you mean. Thanks!